# Still can not handle HTTPS request in proxy servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, https

I have developed a proxy servlet under Tomcat, the servlet receive the request from client and and forward to another proxy server, before forwarding, it will authenticate with the proxy server. Now it can process the HTTP request very well but can not receive the HTTPS request. So this proxy servlet is not perfect.

I have searched google and read many posts in this forum, esp this one:

[Developing a proxy servlet that can handle HTTPS connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150578/developing-a-proxy-servlet-that-can-handle-https-connections/12301228#12301228)

I configured the Tomcat to listen on port 8443, as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" redirectPort="8080"/>
```

I deployed the servlet within eclipse, locally, and I set the browser proxy to 127.0.0.1:8080, but bypass it for localhost.

When I browse https:// localhost:8443/ I can see the https request received in servlet log(by calling request.getScheme() and request.isSecure()). But if i browse https://www.google.com, it can not get connected and my proxy servlet didn't catch the request.

I also override the service() method and print the request.getMethod() and still failed to catch the HTTPS request.

What should I do?

All I want is get the HTTPS request and add the authentication and forward to the next proxy server.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to implement man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: an so it is obvious that this doesn't work. SSL certificate cannot be verified if you intercept and switch the certificate in the middle using your proxy. it's a security restriction.

Comment: if you just want a proxy server, you should try this http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/httpproxy.htm

Comment: We use a proxy for compression purpose, and the proxy servlet is used to do the authentication and some statistic job.

Comment: I saw your link, it seems it support https request. I will check it but not sure how I can authenticate with the proxy server.

Comment: Many client will connect to proxy server and each client has its own uid/password.

Comment: this requires advanced knowledge of proxy server. you might want to consider using to commercially available proxy software.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way SSL proxies work.  If you set your HTTPS proxy to `localhost:8080`, then your browser will dutifully connect to `localhost:8080` and use the `CONNECT` verb to tunnel SSL traffic through the HTTP proxy connection.  Without doing this, SSL wouldn't be particularly secure and any proxy server administrator could trivially read one's credit card details next time someone decided to buy something from Amazon or check their bank balance or sign up for a recurring-payment adult entertainment web site or whatever it is that people do that requires SSL these days.

It doesn't appear that you've told your browser anything about this new SSL proxy on port 8443, so I'm not sure why you think it would be used.  It won't.  You *may* be able to tell your browser to use an SSL-based proxy server - ie, set your proxy as`https://localhost:8443`, but even then it will use `CONNECT`-based SSL tunneling, so there's really no point except still slower connections.

If all you really need to do is forward this request on to another proxy, you need to forward the `CONNECT` method to the upstream proxy and include the appropriate authentication information.

Comment: I tried to set the proxy on 8080 and 8443, both can not received CONNECT command. any idea?